# Cocoa - how to detect if Mac is on Ethernet connection, and no WiFi

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, reachability

I need to know through the Cocoa APIs if a Mac is specifically connected to the internet through an Ethernet connection, or through WiFi. I am using the Reachability class from Apple to detect a WiFi connection, but there doesn't seem a way to see if the Mac is on an ethernet (wired) connection.

I've also looked at the [SCNetworkReachabilityFlags](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) (which Reachability is based off) but can't find a good way to tell which one is for ethernet connections.

Would love some help.

Comment: You can tell if there is reachability though, right?  So what if you checked if it wasn't wifi-- wouldn't it naturally mean that it's an ethernet connection?  no idea if that's a valid idea, just wondering

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to execute some scripts even if your app is running in sandbox environment. You can try to check Wi-Fi state using this command:

```
networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi
```

Also, from own experience, this sample maybe helpful:

```
NSString *scriptCode  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \"%@\"", 
                                                   @"networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi"];
NSDictionary *errorDict = nil;
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc]initWithSource:scriptCode];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *returnDescriptor = [script executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];

NSLog(@"%@", returnDescriptor.stringValue);
```

This works on OSX > 10.8.